# How to understand the ClassCastException when Implement a Generic Interface

Tags: java, generic-programming

1. when I consume records from Kafka, I got a ClassCastException.
   the problem is:

   1. `KafkaAvroDeserializer implement Deserializer<V>`, `deserialize()` method return `Object`.
   2. create a `Consumer<String, KafkaMessage`> consumer, and specify the `KafkaAvroDeserializer`;
   3. when I consume the message, It seems a `KafkaMessageObject`, but it truly a avro GenericData/
2. I made a demo:

```
    private class KafkaMessage {}

    private class AvroGeneric {}

    class Record<K, V> {
        K k;
        V v;
    }

    interface DeSerialize<T> {
        T deserializer();
    }

    class AvroDeserializer implements DeSerialize {
        @Override
        public Object deserializer() {
            return new AvroGeneric();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenericDiff() {
        // KafkaMessage is what I want.
        Record<String, KafkaMessage> record = new Record<>();

        // consume from xxx, get a AvroGenricObject. 
        DeSerialize<KafkaMessage> deSerialize = new AvroDeserializer();
        record.v = deSerialize.deserializer();

        // this is the problem, a AvroGeneric is assigned to a KafkaMessage variable.
        KafkaMessage v = record.v;
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

3. What I want to ask:

   1. does the generic type is Object.class? or what is generic type? (泛型是什么东西)
   2. how to prevent this problem when generic is not dependable? (怎么避免这样的ClassCastException)

Comment: Generics tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: thanks Abra, I get it in the tutoral's Type Erasure Section